# How to audit log the query in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to log the Audit log for activity happening on Mysql server. I want to log precise query like Delete, Insert, update, drop, truncate etc.

Please help if anybody has solution for this requirement.

Comment: Enable `MySQL GENERAL LOG` to audit all queries on server. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

Comment: Hello I did this but in case of General log it logs everything and we can't restrict them but I don't want to log select query instead I would like to log only few  queries like Delete, update, insert etc it is not possible to filter it in case of general logs

Comment: All queries altering your data should be in your binlogs. Just enable those, & you get a nice 'point-in-time' recovery tool as a bonus. It however does _not_ log the user performing this query.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is the BInary Bin Log:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

```
The binary log is not used for statements such as SELECT or SHOW that do not modify data. To log all statements (for example, to identify a problem query), use the general query log. See Section 5.2.2, “The General Query Log”.

Running a server with binary logging enabled makes performance slightly slower. However, the benefits of the binary log in enabling you to set up replication and for restore operations generally outweigh this minor performance decrement.
```